# Powerline on Mac OS X not working as expected

Tags: vim, vim-powerline

[image: as the image show , after installing the powerline for vim some symbols work not so good.]

as the image shows , after installing the powerline for vim, some symbols are not working.

For searching google i thought there maybe problems with the patch fonts. But after trying i cannot solve this problem. Could someone help me?

```
Environment: Mac OSX 10.8.2, iTerm2.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See “[Custom font not working for iTerm2.](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/issues/58)” issue.

Comment: no it cant help me with this problem. After add font rightly there still '??' in powerline...

Comment: @Scen Did you really read it? You must update iterm2 (AFAIR to developed version, not to some release). Just adding font is not enough. For old versions of iterm2 this bug has RESOLVED WONTFIX status.

Comment: Finally i get done of it. I only remove all of my vim files and copy them from my ubuntu old files. It seems like something went wrong in my config file or something .@ZyX thanks a lot, but i really read it and this issue isn`t caused by the verson of iterm2.

Answer (score 4):

--For all the noobs, with attention deficit, like my self.

I had the same issue, the solution was much more basic than than installing the fonts, but was not mentioned anywhere else: manually setting the fonts in your terminal (still need to make sure you have the fonts installed).

In iTerm2: iTerm > preferences > profiles > text > Regular font & non ASCII font.

In Terminal : Terminal > preferences > profiles > text > fonts

Comment: Actually I don't get how this did not get way more upvotes. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

Install [powerline-shell fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) and change in your iTerm2 the text's setting with Inconsolata font for exemple.

Answer (score 2):

iTerm2 -> Preferences... -> Text -> Font & Non-ASCII Font -> Choose Inconsolata for Powerline

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me this vim config solved the problem:

```
g:Powerline_symbols = 'unicode'
```

In some cases it could also be needed:

```
set t_Co=256
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on iTerm 2, make sure you go into your settings and set both the regular font and the non-ascii font to powerline compatible fonts or the prompt separators and special characters will not display correctly as it is happening in your case.